# How to add IFERROR to long formula in google sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheets

Sorry, but I am a beginner to using formula's like vlookup/index/match etc. I have googled a ton of stuff and have been learning a lot but I can't seem to figure out this one thing.

I have the formula:

```
=index($C$58:$C$68,match(
  AVERAGE(
    VLOOKUP(F4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0),
    vlookup(G4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0),
    vlookup(H4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0),
    vlookup(I4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0),
    vlookup(J4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0),
    vlookup(K4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0),
    vlookup(L4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0)),
  $D$58:$D$68,1))
```

This is averaging a bunch of data for me. The problem is, if there is no data selected in each cell, it comes up witha #N/A in the formula box, which just looks bad.

I saw the IFERROR function and have been flirting with it but can't seem to figure out how to add this function to my already existing formula. I would like the box to just be blank. =IFERROR(m4, " ") is what i added but it comes up with RRO in the box.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

First I would replace the series of VLOOKUPs with an arrayformula, and then apply the IFERROR outside :

```
=index($C$58:$C$68,match(AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F4:L4,$C$58:$D$68,2,0), 0))), $D$58:$D$68,1))
```